# What is the unique call to prayer in Sanaatana Dharma?

Tags: puja, prayer

Sanaatana Dharma says God (Ishwara) is only one. So what is the unique call to prayer in Sanaatana Dharma to praise Ishwara?

Just Like

1. Adhan, the Muslim call to prayer
2. Barechu, the Jewish call to prayer
3. Church bells, the Christian call to prayer

Comment: There really isn't an equivalent to the Abrahamic idea in our traditions. One could argue that the call to prayer was the sunrise. Faithful rose before the sunrise to perform the sandhya rituals.

Comment: Unique call to prayers in Sanatan Dharma are: Mantras, Stotras....

Answer (score 2):

**Aarti** is the call to prayer during Puja Prarthna in Temples or at home.

Aarti is a prayer which is usually sung. Dholak, Ghanti or bell and many other instruments are played when Aarti is done. A burning camphor is shown to the Devi and Devta in circles. For reference, please have a look at [Ganga Aarti at Kashi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iplTu8D6JxU).

Any elaborate puja is usually ended with Aarti. Even if one may not have participated in actual puja attentively, it is usually advised to take part in final Aarti (as I've observed being a practicing Hindu). Everyone gathers towards the primary diety and where Aarti is being performed, singing in chorus. Once Aarti is over, everyone takes blessing of the burning camphor.

[Nitya Kram Puja Prakash, Gita Press](https://www.amazon.in/Nitya-Karm-Puja-Prakasha-Hindi-ebook/dp/B07BFVTDKZ) lists down Aartis and Pujan vidhi for each Devi and Devta : Shiva, Durga, Krishna, Lakshmi, Ganesh, Surya etc. As you can see, puja is ended with an Aarti with camphor.

> [image: Durga Aarti]
> Aarti of Durga Devi

Comment: There is one special Aarti sung in most of the temples very early in the morning around 5 A.M. or so .It is  called "Kakad Aarti" in Maharashtra.